# concatinating tcl lists into one list

Tags: list, tcl

I have a procedure that returns a single element or a list of elements. I am trying to concatenate all the returned elements into a single list.

```
set childList [list];
foreach item $myList {
    lappend childList $item; 
    set tempChildList [::myproc $item];  #for different items it will return either single element or a list of elements. 
    if {[llength $tempChildList] > 0} {
        lappend childList $tempChildList;
    }
}
```

So now in my last statement when i `lappend` `$tempChildList` into `childList` it forms a list of lists like below

```
{a {b c} {d e f} {g {h i}} j}
```

but i want to concatenate the `childList` and `tempChildList` so that my final result will be

```
{a b c d e f g h i j}
```

i was thinking of using `concat` command but the issue is it wont concat the nested lists like `{g {j i}}` in my above use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I recommend not flattening the list, but rather being more careful during its construction. In particular, flattening has problems where the list contains compound words (which can result in things going horribly wrong when you do a fancy demo, and things like that). By being more careful, knowing what sort of result you're getting from `::myproc` (and assuming that's a simple list), you can then produce a simple concatenated list quite easily:

```
set childList [list]
foreach item $myList {
    lappend childList $item {*}[::myproc $item]
}
```

Note that if you're keen on returning a single item from `::myproc`, return it with this:

```
return [list $theItem]
```

Though if `$theItem` is a simple word (e.g., some kind of ID) you can get away without being careful.

Answer (score 3):

If you can import the [`struct::list`](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_list.html) module, you can do this:

```
% package require struct::list
1.8.1
% set oldlist {a {b c} {d e f} {g {h i}} j}
% set newlist [::struct::list flatten -full $oldlist]
a b c d e f g h i j
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that might work:

```
proc flatten {lst} {
    while 1 {
        set newlst [concat {*}$lst]
        if {$newlst == $lst} { break }
        set lst $newlst
    }
    return $newlst
}

set lst {a {b c} {{{1 2} 3} 4} {d e f} {g {h i}} j}
puts [flatten $lst]
```

Output:

```
a b c 1 2 3 4 d e f g h i j
```

## Discussion

Take a look at the following interactive session:

```
(1) % set lst {a {b c} {d e f} {g {h i}} j}
a {b c} {d e f} {g {h i}} j

(2) % set newlst [concat {*}$lst]
a b c d e f g {h i} j
```

Notice that when we set the `newlst` in step 2, the result is almost what we want. Now, just repeat step 2 until the `lst` and `newlst` are equal--that's when we know that we have flatten the list completely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
% set list {a {b c} {d e f} {g {h i}} j}
 {a {b c} {d e f} {g {h i}} j}
% set newlist [regsub -all "\{|\}" $list ""]
 a b c d e f g h i j
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `lappend childList $tempChildList` , you can use

`set childlist "$childlist $tempChildList"`

```
if {[llength $tempChildList] > 0} {
   set childlist "$childlist $tempChildList"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
% set str {a {b c} {d e f} {g {h i}} j}

% while {1} {if [regexp -- {\\{} $str] {set str [join $str]} else {break}}

% set str

% a b c d e f g h i j
```